# Menu links going underneath an iframe on page rendering pdf content

Tags: html, css, iframe

We have Top navigation menu which has hover. In the content section of the page we have an iframe the src to[image] which is a pdf file. So the iframe renders a pdf file in it.

When the user hovers on the menu the sub navigation goes below the pdf iframe.

Any help ? How can i render the menu above the iframe.

Comment: it would be helpful if you share a link or reproduce it on jsfiddle. Meanwhile you can try z-index

Answer (score 0):

Things like this can usually be fixed with [z-index.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) Note that z-index only affects elements that have a position property of `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute`.